# Eclipse - Rebuild project on config change setting

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, momentics

Where on Earth is it?

I changed the setting by accident to do it every time I change a project configuration and it's driving me crazy.

I'm using Eclipse 3.4 and CDT 5.0.2. This is QNX Momentics 4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up going menu per menu until I got it:

**Window -> Preferences -> QNX -> General Preferences**